# Delphi assembler constant 'eof'

Tags: delphi, assembly, delphi-7

There seems to be an undocumented constant `eof` in asm block context. This was tested using Delphi 7.

```
program TestEof;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
var
  example : Integer;
begin
  asm
    mov example, eof
  end;
  writeln(example);
  readln;
end.
```

This prints out `14`.

Where does that constant `eof` and it's value value `$0E` or `14` come from?

---

EDIT: this is the compilation result

```
...
call @InitExe
// mov example, eof
mov [example], $0000000e
// writeln(example)
mov eax, [$004040a4]
mov edx, [example]
call @Write0Long
call @WriteLn
call @_IOTest
// readln;
...
```

Answer (score 5):

`Eof` is in fact a [function defined in the `System` unit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Eof).

In the implementations of Delphi that I have at hand, Delphi 6 and XE2, `Eof` is implemented as an [intrinsic routine](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Delphi_Intrinsic_Routines) that results in a call to one of the following functions, as appropriate:

```
function _EofFile(var f: TFileRec): Boolean;
function _EofText(var t: TTextRec): Boolean;
```

I have no idea why your assembler code is turned into `mov [...],$0000000e`. You point out in a comment that the `System` unit itself makes use of `eof` in `asm` code, for example in `TextOpen`. The same code in XE2 is now pure Pascal and searches for a value of `$1A` instead of `$0E`. This would very much appear to be an implementation detail. If you want to understand why this is so then I think you will need to reverse engineer the code in the `System` unit, or see if the engineers at Embarcadero will explain the implementation to you.

Comment: This is actually used in `system.pas` as well. See `TextOpen` function. After `//if  (f.Buffer[i] == eof)`. Line `CMP byte ptr [ESI].TTextRec.Buffer[EAX],eof`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is a built-in. The builtin calls the rtl helper which are the functions that you specify, but can also do generate code and call other functions (e.g. iotest). The EOF might be some internal sequence number for the build-in, to help streamline multiple built-ins that are similar (e.g. all IOCheck/IOTest builtins) but without compiler source that is guesswork.

Comment: And in XE2 the equivalent code looks for `$1A`. This is clearly implementation detail in System.pas. What problem are you trying to solve or is this just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Marco I actually think that eof in asm is different from eof in pascal. See Egon's first comment. But I do agree that it's all a bit academic unless you are the compiler vendor.

Comment: @Marco When you say "built-in", is that different from "intrinsic" as per the documentation link that I provided in the answer?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan if you look into the `TextOpen` function windows version, then after encountering this character the file will be truncated. In the linux version `cEOF` is used, which is `$1A`.

Comment: @egon In XE2 the Windows version uses `cEOF` too. Can I ask again, is this just curiosity?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan mostly curiosity and because TextOpen truncated the file. So essentially I got the reason why it was truncated, but I couldn't figure out why it should compile to that value `$0E`, instead of `$1A`.

Comment: David, EOF (hex 1A, decimal 26) has meant EOF since the early days of DOS. It's the standard end of file character, and (ages ago - pre-DOS 5, IIRC) used to be required in text files to indicate where the file actually stopped. It's documented as EOF in any standard ASCII table. If you have GExperts, for instance, look at their ASCII chart.) If you use `copy con test.txt` from a command prompt in Win7, you can type a line of text and then hit F6 to insert an EOF char, the same way you used to do it with early DOS versions.

Comment: @ken where does 0E come from?

Comment: @David, I don't know. It's defined in the ASCII table as `SO`, or `Shift Out`. IIRC, a lot of the ASCII codes were derived from teletypes and terminals (which is where things like `CR` and `LF` came from, along with `STX` and `ETX`, 0x02 and 0x03 - 'start of text` and 'end of text' respectively). I can't see any reason it would show up in the OP's code, though.

Comment: @Ken White: So [the Wikipedia ASCII table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) is *not* a 'standard ASCII table'? In this table, `#26` (`#$1A`) is called  `SUB` (substitute).

Comment: @Ken White: Still, you are right, it seems. Wikipedia says that `^Z` (that is, `#26`) is commonly used as the [EOF character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file).

Comment: @Andreas That's how you terminate the interactive Python interpreter on Windows isn't it. Whoever closed an input stream with ^N?

Comment: @Andreas, yo're right. I must have remembered wrong about the chart; I just looked, and in fact it isn't labeled EOF as I thought. The #26 being EOF in text files, though, I was certain was right. I remember it well. :)