# Why does Delphi 7 truncate file after ASCII code 14 when opening in Append mode?

Tags: delphi, ascii

I'm working on some legacy software written in Delphi 7 which runs on Windows. I've minified the problem to the following program:

```pascal
var f: text;
begin
  assign(f, 'a.txt');
  rewrite(f);
  writeln(f, 'before' + chr(14) + 'after');
  close(f);

  assign(f, 'a.txt');
  append(f);
  close(f);
end.
```

I expect it to create `a.txt` file containing `"before#14after#13#10"` and then append nothing to it. However, after I run this program on Windows, I see `before` in `a.txt` instead, like if Delphi's `append` truncates the file. If I do not re-open the file, it shows `before#14after#13#10` as expected.

If I write something (`FooBar`) in the re-opened file, it's appended, but as if the file was already truncated: `beforeFooBar`.

This effect does not occur with any other character between 0 and 32, even with 26 (which stands for EOF).

Is this a bug in Delphi or a well-defined behavior? What is so special about `chr(14)`?

Comment: It works as expected in both Delphi 4 (Windows 95) and Delphi 10.3 (Windows 7). I don't have access to any Delphi 7 installation at the moment. (ASCII 14 is SHIFT OUT, by the way.)

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for checking other versions! I'll keep digging locally.

Comment: I can confirm: using Delphi 7 and debugging the file is written as intended (sizes 14 bytes), but when `append()` is called, the file's length is truncated to 6 bytes. I can only assume that ASCII 14 is not really considered "text", while the function tries to find an end of a line. Consider this as undefined behaviour.

Comment: Strangely, indeed an EOF itself is preserved (though it's decimal 26 and not 27).

Comment: Found in another chat: looks like Delphi 7 treats 14 as 26 for some reason: if it's found in the last 128 bytes of the file, the file is truncated, see [here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Append.html).

Comment: Ok, wild guess: someone wrote `eof` in the source code of Delphi 7 assuming it's a correct constant, but it [turns out to be 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702908/delphi-assembler-constant-eof) O_O

Comment: Looks like it (line 4273 of system.pas), it should be `cEOF`.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz (or yeputons himself): can you please write an answer? Maybe even a binary patch could be made to address this bug.

Comment: @yep 's find. If source is not available, this line `CMP     byte ptr [ESI].TTextRec.Buffer[EAX],eof` should be `CMP     byte ptr [ESI].TTextRec.Buffer[EAX],cEOF` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to some friends from a chat and Sertac Akyuz from comments: it looks like a bug in Delphi 7.

It's supposed to have special handling of the EOF symbol (ASCII 26), quoting from [here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System_Append.html):

> Note: If a Ctrl+Z (ASCII 26) is present in the last 128-byte block of the file, the current file position is set so that the next character added to the file overwrites the first Ctrl+Z in the block. In this way, text can be appended to a file that terminates with a Ctrl+Z.

Kind of [CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) backward compatibility, I guess.

However, there is a bug in the implementation of `TextOpen` for Windows (see `Source/Rtl/Sys/System.pas` from your Delphi 7 installation around line 4282):

```
@@loop:
        CMP     EAX,EDX
        JAE     @@success

//    if  (f.Buffer[i] == eof)

        CMP     byte ptr [ESI].TTextRec.Buffer[EAX],eof
        JE      @@truncate
        INC     EAX
        JMP     @@loop
```

Here it says `eof` instead of `cEof`. Unfortunatley, that compiles for some reason [and it even appeared on StackOverflow already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702908/delphi-assembler-constant-eof). There is a label called `@@eof` and that's pretty much it.

Consequence: instead of having special case for 26, we have special case for 14. The exact reason is yet to be found.